# Case statement in MYSQL, Case not found for?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `CASE` statement that takes in the first **40** records of a table, it has different procedures based on a counter - `@COUNT`. 
Unfortunately when I run the procedure without a `else` it does not work and gives a `Case not found for CASE statement (Error 1339)`.

But when I do have the else it works fine but it runs the last day twice, so I have a duplicate of the last date.

Any reason for this? Please check my code below..a lot has been removed

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `init`(In dID INT)

BEGIN  
    DECLARE first40 CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT * FROM tbl
                WHERE tbl.id = dID
                ORDER BY tbl.datum ASC
                LIMIT 40;

    OPEN first40;

    SET @COUNT = 0;
REPEAT FETCH first40 INTO Tid, Tdt, Tcls, Thgh, Tlw, Tvol, Tnms_id;
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1;
CASE 
WHEN @COUNT = 1 THEN 

WHEN @COUNT>= 2 AND @COUNT < 9 THEN 

WHEN @COUNT = 9 THEN 

WHEN @COUNT >= 10 AND @COUNT < 12 THEN 

WHEN @COUNT = 12 THEN

WHEN @COUNT = 13 THEN

WHEN @COUNT = 14 THEN

WHEN @COUNT = 15 THEN

WHEN @COUNT = 16 THEN

WHEN @COUNT >= 17 AND @COUNT < 20 THEN

WHEN @COUNT >= 20 AND @COUNT < 26 THEN

WHEN @COUNT = 26 THEN

WHEN @COUNT >= 27 AND @COUNT < 34 THEN 

WHEN @COUNT = 34 THEN 

WHEN @COUNT > 34 AND @COUNT <= 40 THEN 
    END CASE; 

INSERT INTO .....
            VALUES ....;

UNTIL done END REPEAT;

CLOSE first40; 

END
```

Comment: If you leave the else out and change the limit to `limit 39`, do you still get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to easily add the `ELSE` back into the CASE (unlike a SELECT query, ELSE is **required** in stored procedure CASE blocks), then follow up with this before the INSERT INTO:

```
IF @COUNT <= 40
INSERT INTO .....
            VALUES ....;
```

The reason for repeating the 40th row is that on the 41st pass through the `REPEAT FETCH`, it doesn't get any data so

1. the variables are not updated (but not cleared either)
2. the condition is not checked until *after* your code block prior to the `UNTIL done` portion.

Comment: Why is it doing a `41st pass` if I have limited the query to `40 returned records`?

Comment: Have you read my answer completely? The computer needs to know when to stop but the conditions are checked at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Ok, so done is only set to 1 once 40 records are inserted, and because it is checked after the insert it inserts on the 41st time round. Thanks bro